# Allowing users to mount /dev/loop0

Tags: mount, fstab, slackware

I have a following problem. I need to let normal users mount device /dev/loop0 to a predefined directory /mnt/data. The filesystem of the device is unknown and is to be defined when mount command is invoked via -t option. Furthermore I need to specify an offset when mounting.

I edit the /etc/fstab like this:

```
/dev/loop0 /mnt/data auto user 0 0
```

Then I invoke mount like this:

```
mount loop,offset=32256 hdd.img /mnt/data/
```

Whet I get is:

```
mount: only root can do that
```

What could be the problem?

PS. User is added to "disk" group so he can access /dev/loop*. Rights to access /mnt/data are also granted.

Comment: SOLVED: adding to fstab "/dev/loop0 /mnt/data auto loop,users 0 0"; using losetup -o offset /dev/loop0 hdd.img; mounting like "mount /dev/loop0"; umounting and unbinding like losetup -d /dev/loop0

Comment: FYI: By a) adding users to `disk` group or b) allowing users to mount arbitrary filesystems without `nosuid,nodev` options you are opening your system to quick pwnage. (For example, the user can read private data straight from `/dev/sda1`.)

Comment: In the end switched to "pmount". It allows mounting anywhere under /media/ if device is listed in /etc/pmount.allow. The discussion about disk group is not relevant. If asking for such thing I probably realize the potential risk out of it and yes I know that one can change rules in udev to make loop devices created with another group etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, most people asking for such things *do not* realize the potential risks.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using sudo? You can configure sudo to allow the relevant users to run the mount command as root.

Comment: No, I can't consider "sudo" solution and adding entries in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: @azerIO: Why not?